# Different color in citation with Hyperref

Tags: hyperref, color

I want to highlight some citations by putting them in blue, while the others are in black. I managed to do so by defining this command:

```
\newcommand\mycite[1]{\hypersetup{citecolor=blue}\cite{#1}\hypersetup{citecolor=black}
```

It works as intended, but if I have more than one cite, one of which should be marked and the others not, this does not help.

Here is a minimal example

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[colorlinks,citecolor=black]{hyperref}
\newcommand\mycite[1]{\hypersetup{citecolor=blue}\cite{#1}\hypersetup{citecolor=black}}

\begin{document}
This is OK: \mycite{one} \cite{two}

But I have to chose between \mycite{one,two} or \cite{one,two}

\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{biblio}
\end{document}
```

The content of `biblio.bib` is:

```
@misc{one,
  author = "Author one",
  title = "The reference to this should be in blue",
  howpublished = "Not at all",
  year = "2022"
}

@misc{two,
  author = "Author two",
  title = "The reference to this should be in black",
  howpublished = "Not at all",
  year = "2022"
}
```

This is what I get. I would like in the second case to have one, 2022 in blue and two, 2022 in black.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[colorlinks,citecolor=black]{hyperref}
\makeatletter
\def\bibcite#1#2{%
    \@newl@bel{b}{#1\@extra@binfo}{%
      \hyper@@link[cite\ifcsname citecontext-#1\endcsname \csname citecontext-#1\endcsname\fi]{}{cite.#1\@extra@b@citeb}{#2}%
    }%
  }%

\newcommand\@citespecialcolor{blue}
\makeatother  
  
 
\begin{document}
Give one a specialcolor

\makeatletter
\@namedef{citecontext-one}{special}
\makeatother
\cite{one,two}

Revert again
\makeatletter
\@namedef{citecontext-one}{}
\makeatother
\cite{one,two}

\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{biblio}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I do not understand the solution, but it works like a charm, and it is much better than my ```\mycite``` command, since I can just define in the preamble all the citations that I want to be referenced in blue. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You could load the [natbib](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/natbib) citation management package and define `\bluecitep` and `\bluecitealp` variants of the standard `\citep` and `\citealp` macros.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{biblio.bib}
@misc{one,
  author = "Anna One",
  title = "Thoughts",
  howpublished = "Not at all",
  year = "2022"
}
@misc{two,
  author = "Albert Two",
  title = "Further thoughts",
  howpublished = "Not at all",
  year = "2022"
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[colorlinks,citecolor=black]{hyperref}
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\newcommand\bluecitep[1]{\hypersetup{citecolor=blue}\citep{#1}\hypersetup{citecolor=black}}
\newcommand\bluecitealp[1]{\hypersetup{citecolor=blue}\citealp{#1}\hypersetup{citecolor=black}}

\begin{document}
\setlength\parindent{0pt} % just for this example

This is OK: \bluecitep{one} \citep{two}

Either \bluecitep{one,two} or \citep{one,two}

You \emph{can} have both: (\bluecitealp{one}; \citealp{two})

\bibliography{biblio}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Incidentally, if you prefer square brackets to round parentheses in citation call-outs, be sure to load `natbib` with the `square` option instead of the `round` option.

Comment: Great solution. Thanks!